# How to cast an Object to a class Object (that comes in as a parameter) - Java

Tags: java, reflection, casting

The question may sound confusing, and honestly it is. I'll try to explain myself to my very best.

I'm creating a method, using `Java` `Reflection`, to create a new object from a given class and add it to a `List`.
My class is: Train. So my list is `List<Train>` but what I get from the Reflection created object is a general/normal Object. I mean, the Object that only has the methods `toString`, `hashCode`, etc and not the Train class methods. Therefore I need to cast the Object to an Object of type Train. Something like: `Train t = (Train) Object;`

Where I'm stuck is that the method knows the class, as it comes in a parameter, but I don't know how to cast it... humm confusing I know. Let's show a practical example.

Class Train:

```
public class Train {
private String name;
private int id;
private String brand;
private String model; 


public Train(String name, int id, String brand, String model)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.brand = brand;
    this.model = model;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
(... more sets and gets)
}
```

My method (Here I explain in the comments where I'm stuck):

```
public class NewMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

                List<Train> list = new ArrayList<>();
                qqCoisa(list, Train.class, String.class, int.class);


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro ClassNotFound -> "+ex.getMessage());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro NoSuchMethod - > "+ ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        System.out.println("InstantiationException -> "+ ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalAcessException -> "+ ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        System.out.println("IllegalArgumentException -> "+ ex.getMessage());
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invocation Target Exception -> "+ ex.getMessage());
    }
}



public static void qqCoisa(List list, Class theClass, Class _string, Class _int) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
{

    Constructor ctor = theClass.getConstructor(_string, _int, _string, _string);
    ctor.setAccessible(true);
    Object obj = ctor.newInstance("Train XPTO", 1, "Volvo", "FH12");


    // here is where I'm stuck, In this case I know it is a Train object so 
    // I cast it 'manually' to Train but the way I want to do is to make it 
    // cast for the same type of theClass that comes in the parameter.
    // Something like: theClass t = (theClass) obj;
    Train t = (Train) obj; 
    list.add(t); 

    System.out.println("T toString -> "+t.toString());
    System.out.println("Obj toString -> "+obj.toString());
}
```

If I didn't explain myself please let me know and I'll explain further.

Comment: `t.toString()` and `obj.toString()` are equivalent.

Comment: Yes I know, I forgot to remove them... It was when I was testing other approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the qqCoisa method as follows:

```
public static <T> void qqCoisa(List<T> list, Class<String> _string, Class<Integer> _int) throws Exception
{
    ....
    ....

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T t = (T) obj;
    list.add(t);

    ....
    ....
}
```

This is a generic method that works with parameter of type T. Once you declare the parameter type as T, the Class argument is redundant as method declaration carries this information.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain a bit what it does? I know it has to do with Java Generics but I'm quite new to it.